# How can I rebuild a link in php using mysql db

Tags: php, hyperlink

How to rebuild a link in php 
**original image is here :**

```
http://img.site.com/U/Us/Username/tmb.jpg
```

and i try to rebuild the entire image link with username i have in database

```
http://img.site.com/'.ucfirst(substr($username,1)).'/'.ucfirst(substr($username,2)).'/'.$username.'/tmb.jpg
```

and it's returning in bad format

```
http://img.site.com/Sername/Ername/Username/tmb.jpg
```

and I need to return like this

```
http://img.site.com/U/Us/Username/tmb.jpg
```

$username i have in database so i need take the first letter and then First+Second

Comment: please post some PHP code so we can help you

Comment: `http://img.site.com/'.ucfirst(substr($username,0,1)).'/'.ucfirst(substr($username,0,2)).'/'.$username.'/tmb.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like you're using `substr` incorrectly:
http://php.net/substr

Here's the signature:
`string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )`

You might want want:

```
http://img.site.com/'.ucfirst(substr($username,0,1)).'/'.ucfirst(substr($username,0,2)).'/'.$username.'/tmb.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  echo "http://img.site.com/",substr($username,0,1),"/",substr($username,0,2),"/",$username,"/tmb.jpg";
?>
```

By `substr`ing $str,1, simply starts from 1 not displaying only 1 letter.
and the first letter in arrays(strings) =0